# What is the purpose of return statement in C# programs

Tags: c#

What is the purpose of a return statement.

*Example*:

```
Class Sample 
{
    public static int Main()
    {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
      return 0;
    } 
}
```

In the above program what actually is being returned. Is it returning integer value 0 ? Does this help in the flow of program execution

(This might be a stupid question, but I am eager to know.)

Comment: Do you mean a `return` statement anywhere? Or just in `Main`?

Comment: In Main as well as in other methods

Comment: Here, I also want to know what if `1` is returned in place of `0`?any difference?

Comment: @Javed I was going to ask that question. What about other numbers 2, 3, 4, 5 ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exit code of the application is set to the value returned from Main. This can be used to communicate to the calling application if there was an error or everything succeeded when running the child application.

When running from the console window, the last exit code is set in the environment variable which can be used to control the execution of a batch file for example.

See the following MSDN entry for more info and an example.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fwzzxz2.aspx

Comment: "The exit code of the application is set to the value returned from Main"......What value is returned from main ?

Comment: @subanki - In your example you posted, 0 is returned from Main.

Comment: Is it possible to return a variable ?

Comment: @subakni, yes you can return a variable. In the case of the Main method this must be a variable of type `int`. For other methods, the you must return a value that matches the return type definded for the method, again this return value can be a constant or variable.

Comment: @subanki: returning a variable returns value of it, remember of return type of your method

Comment: So the return value can be anything as long as it matches the data type of the method...hence if the return type is "int" then the value can be anything like 1,2,3,4,5,6,...n. Am I correct ?

Comment: @subanki, That is correct, and that is no different for any other method that has a return type.

Comment: What will happen if I put just "return;" at the end ?

Comment: @subanki, if you use that signature (`public static int Main()`), `return;` won't compile.  However, you can use `public static void Main()` instead.  With that signature, you can use `return;`, and can not return a value.

Answer (score 3):

The exit code of an application (return from main) can be queried in the operating system or in batch programs. In windows, it can be processed in a batch using the %errorlevel% environment var.

```
@echo off
yourpgrogram
echo Your program returned %errorlevel%
```

would brint out Your program returned 0

hth

Mario

Answer (score 2):

From the `Main()` method, the value returned will affect the program's [exit code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status).  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fwzzxz2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> ... returning an integer enables the program to communicate status information to other programs or scripts that invoke the executable file.

Answer (score 2):

return 0 is a convention for no errors in the execution

Comment: @subanki, a different positive value for each error.  You should document what is returned when.